# How to disable automatic line breaking in TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, line-breaks

I have a `TextView` which contains a random string of 60 characters.

The string is a single word and does not contain any white spaces.

The problem is that after certain characters (e.g. `@, &, %`) I get an automatic line break which I do not want.

My desired outcome is that every line is filled up to the end and no random line breaks are present.

I have tried setting `breakStrategy` and updating `hyphenationFrequency`, but this has not helped.

How can I prevent this from happening?

[image]

**UPDATE**: Thanks to @Darkman, this is the solution, which I have written. It checks how many characters can fit into a single line without line-breaks and appends `\n` at the end.

**Be aware that for my use case string has no blank spaces and I am using a monospace font.**

```
fun TextView.toNonBreakingString(text: String?): String {
    if (text == null) return ""
    val container = parent as? ViewGroup ?: return text

    val lineWidth = (container.width - container.paddingStart - container.paddingEnd).toFloat()
    val maxCharsInOneLine = paint.breakText(text, 0, text.length, true, lineWidth, null)
    if (maxCharsInOneLine == 0) return text

    val sb = StringBuilder()
    var currentLine = 1
    var end = 0
    for (i in 0..text.count() step maxCharsInOneLine) {
        end = currentLine * maxCharsInOneLine
        if (end > text.length) end = text.length
        sb.append(text.subSequence(i, end))
        sb.append("\n")
        currentLine = currentLine.inc()
    }

    if (end < text.length) {
        val remainingChars = text.length - end
        sb.append(text.takeLast(remainingChars))
    }

    return sb.toString()
}
```

Comment: Set `android:maxLines="1"` on the `TextView`.

Comment: If it fits into one line ofcourse there is no line-break issue :) As you can see in the screenshot, it won't always fit into a single line and I want my string to be fully visible.

Comment: Then set `android:maxLines="1"`, set appropriate layout rules to control the width, and use autosize attributes to reduce the font size automatically based on the length of the string.

Comment: Autoresize breaks accessibility if user changes font size in Android settings. I really don't want to use this and also I do not want this to be single line from UI perspective. My question is not how to avoid line-breaks, but how to line break only when line reaches end of the layout.

Comment: "Autoresize breaks accessibility if user changes font size in Android settings" -- I do not see how. Autosize will shrink the text to fit, regardless of the user's chosen font scale. If your concern is that the 60 characters will be too small, then use fewer than 60 characters. "I do not want this to be single line from UI perspective" -- so... you want it to be more than one line, yet not more than one line? How does that work, mathematically?

Comment: It feels like you are missing stuff in your question. For example, is this 10-60 character string in the middle of some larger block of text? If so, then your "I do not want this to be single line from UI perspective" starts to make some sense, but then your question has issues (such as a misleading screenshot).

Comment: "Autosize will shrink the text to fit, regardless of the user's chosen font scale", this is exactly how it breaks accessibility. The font size will not be scaled if it is set  e.g. to Largest via Android Settings. This is not desired for visually impaired users. What I meant in my question is that I have a long string with no white space, e.g. "ifj21324%dsigfjsdig$@js%digjsdi", this obviously does not fit into one line and I want it to be fully visible, but it magically line breaks at certain characters such as %,&,@ etc, without reaching the end of the layout as you can see in the screnshot.

Comment: "This is not desired for visually impaired users" -- agreed. However, 60 characters at the largest font size will not fit all screens, just based on the available screen width, let alone any margins or other stuff that consumes horizontal space. "this obviously does not fit into one line and I want it to be fully visible" -- then you have to use autosize to allow the font to shrink. It may not fit the available screen width otherwise.

Comment: I'm fine with my TextView height expanding as much as needed, the problem is clearly visible in the screenshot, if you look at the first line, you will see that it jumps to next line without reaching the end of the layout, similarly the 2nd line, the 3rd line length is fine though and is what I want to achieve for every line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve your desired result is by using `monospace` font, left gravity and a little bit programming.

```xml
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
 
   android:text="akAOCYMKIpVmSwhHtWS%fBFK7eWi%19a590344gZqGQtkTcRv^1lFqH#F@Lhr"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:background="#708BCD"
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:typeface="monospace"/>
```

```java
//Note :: Auto-updated
public final void wrapText(final TextView textView, final String text)
{
    final float textSize = (textView.getTextSize() / 250F) * 150F;
    final int textLen = text.length();
    final int columns = (int)(textView.getWidth() / textSize);
    final int lines = (int)((float) textLen / columns);
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(textLen + lines);
    for(int i=0, n=0; i < textLen; i+=columns, ++n) {
        sb.append(text.subSequence(i, Math.min(textLen, i + columns)));
        if(n<lines) sb.append("\n");
    }
    textView.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

Or

```java
//Note :: Auto-updated
public final void wrapText(final TextView textView)
{
    final float textSize = (textView.getTextSize() / 250F) * 150F;
    final CharSequence text = textView.getText();
    final int textLen = text.length();
    final int columns = (int)(textView.getWidth() / textSize);
    final int lines = (int)((float) textLen / columns);
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(textLen + lines);
    for(int i=0, n=0; i < textLen; i+=columns, ++n) {
        sb.append(text.subSequence(i, Math.min(textLen, i + columns)));
        if(n<lines) sb.append("\n");
    }
    textView.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

Or

```java
// Note :: Self-update
public final String wrapText(final TextView textView, final String text)
{
    final float textSize = (textView.getTextSize() / 250F) * 150F;
    final int textLen = text.length();
    final int columns = (int)(textView.getWidth() / textSize);
    final int lines = (int)((float) textLen / columns);
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(textLen + lines);
    for(int i=0, n=0; i < textLen; i+=columns, ++n) {
        sb.append(text.subSequence(i, Math.min(textLen, i + columns)));
        if(n<lines) sb.append("\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

// Implementation:
// textView.setText(wrapText(textView, "akAOCYMKIpVmSwhHtWS%fBFK7eWi%19a590344gZqGQtkTcRv^1lFqH#F@Lhr"));
```

And you need to call either one of the methods after the layout has been measured. That means outside of `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()` or something similar.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your answer has helped me to come up with a fix. I have updated my question with my implementation. Same idea, but a bit different execution.

Answer (score 1):

I know this solution is little bit odd but if anything is not desirable or if you did't find any solution in near future, then you can use:

```
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/file_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/file_name"
                android:textColor="?attr/primaryText"/>

        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but it's not something I want. I would rather have full visibility of the string with 'magic' line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If your API level is 26+ then you can use the following XML tag to set the justification in android.

```
android:justificationMode="inter_word"
```

Or you can use [this](https://github.com/nikoo28/justify-textview-android) GitHub library for all the API levels

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have tried both solutions and they are not working because in this case my string is a single word which is very long. It still automatically jumps to next line on characters %,&,@ ,! and some others.